# git lfs pull in repository produces an error about dial tcp

Tags: git, tcp, proxy, git-lfs

`git lfs pull` in repository produces the following error:

> oobarbazanoo@LAPTOP-CQEVT11F MINGW64 /c/Projects/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging/ecom-oneapp-data-staging (master)
>   $ git lfs pull
>
> batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   batch response: Post https://yaroslavvaltech@bitbucket.org/doesnotmatter/ecom-oneapp-data-staging.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup helloInternet: no such host
>   ...

It seems that the issue is about the proxy being configured in a wrong way. So, what I decided to try is to run the command `git config --global --unset http.proxy` and then the `git lfs pull` once more. It did not help, I got the same error as above.

I am using Windows 10. Here is the copy of the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.file`:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

As you can see there is no `helloInternet` host being specified in it. Actually the file is totally blank, since it contains only comments.

What may I do to fix it?

So, here are my environment variables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fhKx.png)

After deleting the `http_proxy` variable and trying out the command everything works just fine.

Comment: Do you have an `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` variable set in the environment, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: @brianm.carlson, oh! Thank you a lot! You are my saver. I updated my answer.

Comment: @brianm.carlson, why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure. Let me do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and most other tools that handle proxies support multiple environment variables to control the proxies used. For HTTP, this is the `http_proxy` environment variable, and for HTTPS, both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are consulted.

It looks like you may have one or both of those set in your environment; unsetting them may help you connect directly to the server.